# Oracle regular expression regexp_like

Tags: oracle

I have simple question.
why would :

```
select regexp_like( (select 'https://www.hotmail.com' from dual) ,'(f|ht)tps?:') from dual ;
```

not work?

Comment: For the same reason `select 'A'='A' from dual;` 'does not work'? (something similar works on other RDBMSs - [eg postgres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/440))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect this query to do?

`regexp_like` is a regular expression version of the `LIKE` statement so it makes sense to use it in the same sorts of places that you would use a `LIKE`.  You wouldn't try to directly `SELECT` the result of a `LIKE` statement.  You could, however, embed the `regexp_like` in a `case` statement.  For example

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select (case when regexp_like( 'https://www.hotmail.com' ,'(f|ht)tps?:')
  2               then 'true'
  3               else 'false'
  4           end) does_it_match
  5*   from dual
SQL> /

DOES_
-----
true
```

`regexp_like` is a function that returns a `boolean`.  Oracle SQL, however, does not support the `boolean` data type so you cannot directly `SELECT` the result of the function just like you couldn't `SELECT` a function you write that returns a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Because for some strange reason, although regexp_like looks like a function on a first glance, it is not a function in reality, but is a *condition* (an integral part of SQL syntax).

But, more confusingly, it is a function if used in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
   x BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
   x := regexp_like( 'a', 'b' ) ;
END;
/
```

Comment: `regexp_like` is a function.  Because it is a function that returns a `boolean`, however, and SQL does not support the `boolean` data type, you cannot directly `SELECT` the result of the function just like you couldn't `SELECT` a function you write that returns a `boolean`.

Comment: @Justin that would be great info to edit into your answer too?

Comment: @JackDouglas - Good point.  Done.